# Why 'KnownTypeAttribute' still required when I am not returning derived type from my domain service?

Tags: wcf, wcf-ria-services

I have a `BaseModel` and a `ChildModel` in my namespace. I had operations in DomainService returning both of them, and was getting an exception that said 'apply KnownTypeAttribute' to the base class. I applied, it worked.

But, if I don't expose any operation returning DerivedType in my DomainService, then also I am bound to apply this Attribute on the BaseModel, otherwise I get the exception.

Can anybody explains why is this happening ?

```
public class MyService: DomainServiceBase
{
    public BaseModel Get()
    {
        return new BaseModel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will happen if WCF gets a message which uses the derived type. In this case since you have not used the known types attribute, WCF will not know where to find this child domain type, and throe an exception.

Comment: But, I am not exposing or returning "ChildType" objects from any of the methods in the "DomainService" class. So, there is no way WCF will receive a message that says to serialize a "ChildType" of object.

Comment: when do you get the exception, when you start the service or when it gets some message? does it happen with any message? my guess is that the client sends the child type. since it inherits from base type it is legal

Comment: No, I am returning only BaseType. Not the derived type. I had both of them being returned, but just for testing, I removed the method returning the DerivedType, and still I had to keep the Attribute on the BaseType for it to work properly.

Comment: when do you get the exception, when runing the service or wehn receiving a message? what if you add an operation with no parameters, do you also get this exception?